# How to sort plsql collection on the basis of one column

Tags: oracle, sorting, plsql, collections, user-defined-types

My nested collection type is

```
TYPE Ty_Utils IS RECORD(
    Utils_Master  Ty_Util_Master,
    Utils_Details Ty_Tb_Utils_Details);
```

So, one one case I am getting the collection with values as in a loop

```
Ty_Utils.utils_details(k).seq_no:=2
Ty_Utils.utils_details(k).seq_no:=3
Ty_Utils.utils_details(k).seq_no:=1
```

I have to sort the all the values of above collection, i.e. `Ty_Utils.utils_details` according to `seq_no` in ascending order. Some of the `seq_no` will be null. I should keep those to the last.

Please help

Comment: Could you explain why do you need to sort {L/SQL collectios ? What is the mail problem you are trying to solve using this "sorted collection" ? It is not simple, there is no method to sort the PL / SQL collection, probably the easiest way is to convert this option to a table (materialized wodok) and use SELECT ... ORDER BY, maybe easier to not use collectiona at all in the main problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Hi, because it will be IN parameter to one function.According to that sorted collection all the line by line amount will be deducted from each customer account as per customer preference.

Comment: And why this function requires a sorted collection ? What this function is supossed to do ?

Comment: This function will simply take the collection and use line by line from INPUT collection to utilize the customer bank account or debit.So, it need sorted collection

Comment: How is `Ty_Tb_Utils_Details` defined?

Comment: I suggest defining a map type (associative array, indexed by PLS_INTEGER). Put data into the map using SEQ_NO as the index, then pull them out in order by sequence. Either that or [code yourself up a nice little bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort), which will probably be good enough, and is simple to implement. Best of luck.

Comment: 1. How are the component types defined? Is `utils_details` a collection, too? (Judging by `utils_details(k)`).) 2. There are no "collections" in PL/SQL, that is a generic name. The collection types are varray, nested table, and associative array. Which kind of collection are you using? You may need to include the ordering within the nested type, but how you do that depends on exactly which type you are using.

Comment: *"This function will simply take the collection and use line by line from INPUT collection to utilize the customer bank account or debit"* Relying on the order of entries in an array seems an incredibly fragile way of handling financial transactions. Particularly if the sorting key can be null..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends how your referenced types are created. If `Ty_Util_Master` and `Ty_Tb_Utils_Details` are SQL types then you can do this.

You haven't provide any details for most of your schema, so all the objects in this demo are guesswork. Referenced types:

```
create or replace type Ty_Util_Master as object (
    id number,
    txn_date date
);
/
create or replace type Ty_Utils_Detail as object (
    seq_no number,
    amt number,
    txn_type varchar2(3)
);
/
create or replace type Ty_Tb_Utils_Details as table of Ty_Utils_Detail;
/
```

Sample package:

```
create or replace package tst as

    type  pl_Ty_Util is record (
        header  Ty_Util_Master
       , details Ty_Tb_Utils_Details
    );
    procedure process_utils  ( p_util in pl_Ty_Util);
end tst;    
/

create or replace package  body tst as

    procedure process_utils 
        ( p_util in pl_Ty_Util)
    is
    begin
        dbms_output.put_line('id = '||p_util.header.id);
        for idx in ( select t.* 
                     from table(p_util.details) t
                     order by t.seq_no nulls last)
        loop
             dbms_output.put_line('#'||idx.seq_no ||' '|| idx.amt ||' '|| idx.txn_type );
        end loop;
    end process_utils;
end tst;    
/
```

Test harness:

```
declare
    l_utils  tst.pl_Ty_Util;
begin
    l_utils :=  tst.pl_Ty_Util(Ty_Util_Master(42, sysdate)
                        , Ty_Tb_Utils_Details(
                             Ty_Utils_Detail(3, 3000, 'D')
                             , Ty_Utils_Detail(null, 275, 'C')
                             , Ty_Utils_Detail(1, 5000, 'C')
                             , Ty_Utils_Detail(4, 150, 'D')
                             , Ty_Utils_Detail(2, 2000, 'C')
                             )
                        );
     tst.process_utils(l_utils);       
end;
/
```

If you want to test it [here is a LiveSQL demo (free Oracle TechNet account required)](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/ghs6eoqhzjftimz1qxzjuwja1).